# How can I get constant variable with the global object in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables, dynamic-programming

I wanted to get a constant variable with the [global object](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) to use it dynamically but `global.myconstant` doesn't work but `global.myvar` works.

```
λ node
> const myconstant = true
undefined
> global.myconstant
undefined
> var myvar = true
undefined
> global.myvar
true
> global.const
undefined
```

That I want to do :

```
const myconstant = () => { console.log("ok const"); };
var myvariable = () => { console.log("ok var"); };

const watchlist = {
  myconstant: "file1.html",
  myvariable: "file2.html"
};

Object.keys(watchlist).forEach((taskName) => {
  try {
    global[taskName](); //doesn't work with const
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("error", taskName);
  }
});
```

Actual output :

```
error myconstant
ok var
```

Wanted output :

```
ok const
ok var
```

Live demo : https://repl.it/repls/SunnyScholarlyPasswords

How can I get const variable with string ? **Without replace `const` by `var`**.

Comment: The behaviour you're describing isn't natural to Node. It's specific to REPL you're using. Please, clarify where you intend to use this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only variables declared with `var` get implicitly assigned to the global object. If you want to create a non-reassignable property, you should use `Object.defineProperty` instead. For example, in the browser, referring to `window` instead of `global`:

```js
Object.defineProperty(
  window,
  'myconstant',
  {
    value: () => { console.log("ok const"); },
    configurable: false
  }
);
var myvariable = () => { console.log("ok var"); };

const watchlist = {
  myconstant: "file1.html",
  myvariable: "file2.html"
};

Object.keys(watchlist).forEach((taskName) => {
  try {
    window[taskName]();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("error", taskName);
  }
});

// Won't reassign, and will throw an error in strict mode:
window.myconstant = 'foo';
console.log(typeof window.myconstant);
```

The `configurable: false` is the key, though it's optional - it defaults to `false` anyway. Non-configurable properties can't be modified or deleted.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's uglier than simply using `const`, but it's the only option available, because `const` doesn't create properties on the global object. Feel free to use a helper function to abstract it away, so you could do something like `globalConst('myconstant', () => { console.log("ok const"); });`

Comment: Something like : `myconstant: {file:"file1.html",func:myconstant}` seems more easy to understand for other contributor.

Answer (score 0):

Described behaviour is natural to but not Node REPL but not the code that is evaluated in modules. Variables in module scope don't leak to global because they are defined in [module scope](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper), this applies to both `var` and `const`. This is what will happen in Node module:

```
const myconstant = 1;
var myvariable = 2;

console.log(global.myconstant) // undefined
console.log(global.myvariable) // undefined
```

The reason why this happens in REPL is that the code is evaluated in global scope. Described behaviour could be replicated in module scope with indirect `eval`:

```
(0, eval)(`
  const myconstant = 1;
  var myvariable = 2;
`);

console.log(global.myconstant) // undefined
console.log(global.myvariable) // 2
```

This is the difference between `var` and block-scoped variables (`const`, etc.). When defined in global scope, `var` results in defining a property on global variable (`global` in Node), while `const` doesn't.

If the intention is to define a global, it should be defined as a property:

```
global.myconstant = 1;
global.myvariable = 2;
```

In case it's needed to define global variable that won't be reassigned, a descriptor should be used (as another answer already explains):

```
Object.defineProperty(global, 'myconstant', {
  value: 1,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false
});
```

The use of globals for local purposes is generally discouraged, especially in modular environments like Node.

Comment: I'm not sure of your sentence because we have  `configurable:true` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description

Comment: *because we have configurable:true* - where? This example shows how to define a thing that is similar to `const`, i.e. a constant that cannot be redefined.